# Sqlite3 Syntax Error when inserting strings

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I got into AI and wanted to create a Markov Chain bot in python. I want to save the strings using Sqlite3 but I'm having issues. I mostly code in JS (1.5 years) so this is all new territory for me that has been mapped out by tutorials and such. Therefore the "Ai" part works and prints strings whereas I have gotten no further than creating and labeling the DB. So now I'm stuck (& lost) so help would be appreciated Also, I code using/on "replit" if that matters.

Error message and code below

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 88, in 
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chatter VALUES (' + captured + '),' + '(' + str(loop) + ')' )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "might": syntax error**

```
import spacy
import re 
import markovify
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import warnings
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("Markov.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE chatter (sentence TEXT, chat_number INTEGER)")

print(connection.total_changes)

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

redditOne = open('Relationship.txt')
aita = redditOne.read()

redditTwo = open('Qanon.txt')
anon = redditTwo.read() 

redditThree = open('AITA.txt')
real = redditThree.read()



#print(real)

#utility function for text cleaning
def text_cleaner(text):
  text = re.sub(r'--', ' ', text)
  text = re.sub('[\[].*?[\]]', '', text)
  text = re.sub(r'(\b|\s+\-?|^\-?)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\b','', text)
  text = ' '.join(text.split())
  return text
  
aita = re.sub(r'Chapter \d+', '', aita)
anon = re.sub(r'Chapter \d+', '', anon)
real = re.sub(r'Chapter \d+', '', real)

#apply cleaning function to corpus
aita = text_cleaner(aita)
real = text_cleaner(real)
anon = text_cleaner(anon)


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
aita_doc = nlp(aita)
anon_doc = nlp(anon)
real_doc = nlp(real)


aita_sents = ' '.join([sent.text for sent in aita_doc.sents if len(sent.text) > 1])
anon_sents = ' '.join([sent.text for sent in anon_doc.sents if len(sent.text) > 1])
real_sents = ' '.join([sent.text for sent in real_doc.sents if len(sent.text) > 1])


combined_sents = aita_sents + anon_sents + real_sents + 
#print(combined_sents)

#next we will use spacy's part of speech to generate more legible text
class POSifiedText(markovify.Text):
   def word_split(self, sentence):
      return ['::'.join((word.orth_, word.pos_)) for word in nlp(sentence)]
   def word_join(self, words):
      sentence = ' '.join(word.split('::')[0] for word in words)
      return sentence
#Call the class on our text
generator_2 = POSifiedText(combined_sents, state_size=3)

#now we will use the above generator to generate sentences
# I commented this one out as the sentences "some what" string together and would like to do more research
#for i in range(5):
  #sentence = generator_2.make_sentence()

  #print(sentence)
 
#print 100 characters or less sentences
#print("")

#this sentence gen makes tweet size lengts of 140, google say new is 280 gonna keep simple til i do some research 
for i in range(10):
  loop = i
  captured = generator_2.make_short_sentence(max_chars=140)
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chatter VALUES (' + captured + '),' + '(' + str(loop) + ')' )
 
  
  print(captured)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears "might" was created by your sentence generator. The fact that it caused a syntax error indicates that you didn't quote it properly such that SQLite would treat it as a value to insert, and in fact I do not see any logic that would quote said sentence.

I would encourage you to look up Python format strings, which give you a cleaner way to construct strings, especially ones that contain quotes, e.g.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chatter VALUES ("{}"), ("{}")'.format(captured, str(loop)))
```

In Python, the single quote is interchangeable with the double quote when it comes to constructing strings, as long as you use the same character to start and terminate a string. This makes it really convenient when you need to construct a string that requires either one of these characters.

Lastly, I'm sure you have heard about this, but this is an almost mandatory disclaimer for other people reading this answer: format strings should never be used to parameterize a SQL query that faces the public due to the risk of SQL injection. But for prototypes and scripts run locally with your own data, they are convenient and simple.

Comment: Interestingly I did look up "how to put variables in to a string python" and ".format" did pop up as one of the options to use. But I guess I didn't use it right. got this instead @vincent-la

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 88, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chatter VALUES ("{}"), ("{}")'.format(captured, str(loop)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table chatter has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied```

Comment: It looks like the `VALUES ("stuff"), ("stuff")` syntax isn't being supported so you should use `VALUES ("stuff", "stuff")` syntax instead